# Will FileChannel.lock mutex work across mutliple containers or nodes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, mutex

I'm building a file system based repository as an alternative to my database based repositories. I was planning on using a FileChannel.lock based mutex for concurrency, but then I thought this might not work when the 2+ processes are run from separate containers (separate nodes even) in a kubernetes cluster with a shared volume mount for the filesystem. Does anyone know if the lock will be recognized in this scenario or if it will only work within the same container or system.

Comment: Answer to your question is actually filesystem-dependent. See [this here Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) for base information, maybe it will be enough.

Comment: Thanks, the specific filesystem will be an Azure File Share mounted as a volume in case that will help anyone answering this.

Comment: Azure technically is supposed to support locks ([click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/managing-file-locks)). Then end result is all rainbow if mounted system will properly notify everything about the lock.

Comment: I'm no longer going down this route, so I won't be able to test this anytime soon unfortunately